Is it natural to say "drink it up to this level"?
I want my son to drink warm water in the early morning so that he can easily empty his bowel before going to school because it's not nice if he has to do it at school.
But, he doesn't like it very much. But I still push him to drink some.

Look at the picture above, I want him drink 80% of the water in the glass. So, I point my finger to a point (as shown in the picture) and say "try to drink up to this level".
I am not sure that is natural because "level" doesn't sound natural.
I remember someone say "I drank this much" when he show his fingers like this


No. But something that would be idiomatic is Drink down to here.

You know how eating disorders stem from parents who make food an issue? Same could be said of drinking to go that is pushed from above. Either serve the right amount, or make sweet herb tea or hot chocolate the kid wants to drink anyway. Why is it not nice at school? Just saying.

@YosefBaskin, "wipe his ass after pooing" is yucky and he might miss parts of his lesson if going to the bathroom in the middle of the class?

Why don't you put less water in the glass and tell him to drink it all?

@KateBunting,it's good if he can drink it all, but he keeps complaining, so I have a deal with him.

OMG. Do we really need to hear about this? Maybe you need to teach him how to wipe himself. What these good people are not telling you is that in English, we can point to the glass and say: Come on now, drink up! No parent puts an arrow on a glass and tells there kid to "drink up to here". [water surface]

You are a helicopter parent and setting yourself up for trouble later. I have never ever heard of such a practice.

I would remind people that this is supposed to be a language learning SE, it is not a parenting advice SE.  If you feel compelled to tell other people how you think they should raise their kids, please do it somewhere else.

The "up" in "up to" is referring to the direction that things (i.e. in this case, the water level) are changing to reach that point.  When you drink from a glass, the water level does not go up, so saying "up to" in this situation does not make sense.
However, when you drink from a glass, the water level goes down, so you can say "drink down to this level" instead.
Some other examples:

"Fill the glass up to this level" (filling makes the level go up, so "up to")
"Drain the bathtub down to this level" (draining a tub makes the water level go down, so "down to")
"Boil the soup until it has reduced down to half its volume"
"Inflate the balloon up to this size"


Edit
To follow the OP's preferred method, as shown in the diagram, we could say

try to drink [down] to [here]


try to drink [down] to this level

(My earlier answer didn't go according to the diagram and was an alternative way.)
Earlier Answer
We could say the following while pointing at the desired level:
Try to finish (or 'drink') the amount filled to this level.
Fill to this level and try to finish it.

If I understand the OP correctly, he is asking his son to drink from a full glass until there is only a small amount left, so your versions don't apply.

@Kate Bunting, Oh, I missed that arrow; thanks for pointing out.  I have edited my answer, following Paul's suggestion.
